# How can I connect to a different environment based on a value in the request header in a .NET Core Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I connect to a different environment based on a value in a request header from in a .NET Core Web API project? Basically, a request header will be contain the environment to use, and then the api would use the database, azure storage, and etc for that environment. I'm new to .NET Core, and I'm unsure on how this would work. Would this have to be some sort of middleware or would this be a change in the startup.cs file?

This is an example of what I'm trying to change, I want to change the connections strings based on the request header:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>(serviceProvider =>
           {
               return new Repository(
                    string connectionString,
                    string azureConnectionString
                   );
           });
}
```

Comment: You can DI in a HttpContextAccessor and get request headers from that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: The configuresevice method will be only called once when the server started, so we couldn't modify the connection string.  The workaround should be create two dbcontext or Repository to use. Then you could check the httpcontext's value to and select the right  dbcontext or Repository.

Comment: Hey @BrandoZhang thanks for the answer, would I need to inject both Repository instances and the httpcontext into the controller's constructor and use the httpcontext to decide which repository to use? I guess I'm confused on where I would use the httpcontext.

Comment: Yes, you are right